# General Form of Theta Functions from Functional Equations

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series, complex-integration, theta-functions

From Elliptic Curves: Function Theory, Geometry and Arithmetic by McKean and Moll:

Exercise 3.1.2. Discuss the general solution of the two identities (a) $f(x+2)=f(x)$ and (b) $f(x+2\omega)=e^{ax+b}f(x)$. Hint: Expand $f$ in a Fourier series $\sum{\hat{f}(n)e^{\pi \sqrt{-1}nx}}$ and use (b) to pin down $\hat{f}(n)$. You will see thetas coming out.

The question is, how do I use (b) to pin down $\hat{f}(n)$?

I can write a Fourier series using the information from (a):
$$f(x)=\sum{\hat{f}(n)e^{\pi \sqrt{-1}nx}}$$
where $$\hat{f}(n)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^2{f(x)e^{-\pi \sqrt{-1}nx}}dx$$

To use (b), I thought that I could perhaps integrate the function $\frac{1}{2} f(x)e^{-\pi \sqrt{-1}nx}$ around the perimeter of the fundamental cell (this is the line segment from $0$ to $2$, followed by $2$ to $2 +2\omega$, then $2 +2\omega$ back to $2\omega$, and $2\omega$ to $0$).
Then the contribution from the integrals from $2$ to $2 +2\omega$ and from $2\omega$ to $0$ cancel out due to the $2$-periodicity of $\frac{1}{2} f(x)e^{-\pi \sqrt{-1}nx}$ and since the function is entire and using Cauchy's integral theorem we end up with:
$$\int_0^2{\frac{1}{2}f(x)e^{-\pi \sqrt{-1}nx}}dx=\int_0^2{\frac{1}{2} f(x+2\omega)e^{-\pi \sqrt{-1}n(x+2\omega)}}dx$$

Then:
$$\hat{f}(n)= e^{-2\sqrt{-1}\pi\omega n}\int_0^2{\frac{1}{2} e^{ax+b}f(x)e^{-\pi \sqrt{-1}nx}}dx$$

But now I think I have hit a snag: I know that $\hat{f}(n)$ should contain an $e^{\sqrt{-1}\pi\omega n^{2}}$ term, but it doesn't look like that is going to happen. Have I made a mistake somewhere or should I be using a different technique? I can't think of any other viable way to use (b) that will give me the magical $n^{2}$.

Comment: OK -and this $N$ is the integer for which $\hat{f}(n)$ vanishes for all $n<N$?

Comment: Sorry $N$ is useless, since LHS has to converge even if $N =-\infty$ suppose it is $-\infty$ at first. Now I admit I don't get how it is supposed to yield something similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Jacobi_theta_function

Comment: and of course I meant $f(x+2 \omega) =\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(n) e^{2 i \pi n \omega} e^{i \pi n x} = e^{ax+b} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(n)  e^{i \pi n x} = e^{ax+b} f(x)$

Comment: and it should mean that $a = i \pi k$ with $k$ an integer, since otherwise RHS is not $2$-periodic anymore.  in that case   $ e^{a x+b} f(x) = e^{i \pi k x+b} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(n)  e^{i \pi n x} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^b \hat{f}(n-k)  e^{i \pi n x} = f(x+2 \omega) $ $=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(n) e^{2 i \pi n \omega} e^{i \pi n x} $ i.e. $  e^b \hat{f}(n-k)  =  \hat{f}(n) e^{2 i \pi n \omega} $, hence $\hat{f}(n k) =\hat{f}(0) \prod_{m = 0}^{n-1} e^b e^{-2 i \pi m k \omega} = \hat{f}(0)  e^{bn} e^{- i \pi (n^2-n) k \omega}$

Comment: and $\hat{f}(n k+l) =\hat{f}(l) \prod_{m = 0}^{n-1} e^b e^{-2 i \pi (m k+l) \omega} = \hat{f}(l)  e^{(b-l) n} e^{- i \pi (n^2-n) k \omega}$, i.e. $$f(x) = \sum_{l=0}^{|k|-1}\hat{f}(l)   \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty e^{(b-l) n} e^{- i \pi (n^2-n) k \omega} e^{i \pi (nk+l)x}$$ do you like it ?

Comment: Yes looks good - I've just realised that a gaggle of $n$s are missing from the question so I will fix that.

Comment: I do like it very much and I think I even see thetas coming out. I guess the key is noting that $a$ has to take a very specific form, and that's where the recurrence relation comes from that ultimately spits out the $n^{2}$. I will upvote when I get the reputation, and in the meantime I will see if I can get one of the Jacobi functions to appear.

Comment: yes exactly : if the Jacobi theta function doesn't appear as a special case, there is a problem

Comment: Actually I'm not quite sure how you got $\hat{f}(n-k)  =  \hat{f}(n) e^{i \pi kx}$? This was used in the first line of your 3rd comment.

Comment: If $g(x) = h(x)$ for every $x$,  where the two are Fourier series, then there Fourier coefs are equal. This is because what you wrote in your question, that the Fourier coefs are $\hat{g}(n) = \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T g(x) e^{-2i \pi n x/T} dx$. $ \ \ \ $ and I wrote $e^b \hat{f}(n-k) = \hat{f}(n) e^{i \pi n \omega}$  (the Fourier coefs are functions of $n$, not of $x$)

Comment: Of course. And at the risk of asking another dumb one, should the upper limit of the first product be $n$ not $n-1$?

Comment: no, but you can transform $n^2-n$ into $n^2$ by looking at $f(x-\omega)$. You should write a clean answer, and check if $k=1$ reduces to Jacobi theta